# Where can I change how Citrix XenApp maps drive letters?

Tags: citrix, xenapp

We're running Citrix XenApp 5.0.  When we login, it appears Citrix is overwriting a network drive that is mapped via our logon script (as specified in AD).  The script is definitely firing - I confirmed this by adding another drive mapping and it does appear.  The drive letter is F, and is suppose to map to the user's home directory on the network, but instead it maps to the C:\users\%username% directory on the Citrix server.

I've checked our profiles in XenApp advanced configuration but they are pretty vanilla and I don't see anything that could be causing this.

I appreciate any ideas you can throw my way!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something non-standard in your configuration.  Nothing in Citrix maps the F drive to anything by default.

Answer (score 0):

The path C:\users\%username% seems to me a home folder, is your script mapping to a specific path or to the HOMEDRIVE environment variable, also notice that a citrix server is a terminal server and you should check what is configured on the group policy GPOs that apply on the OU where the citrix server is in,
It should be under computer config. - windows components - terminal services